# Sub sum the same item

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns:

```
A             B
apple_type1   25
apple_type1   15
apple_type1   5
pears_type1  10
pears_type1  3
apple_type2   5
apple_type2   15
```

It is posible to Subsum the column B (without deleting the rows, whithout filters, without Pivot table) like:

```
apple_type1   0
apple_type1   0
apple_type1   45
pears_type1  0
pears_type1  13
apple_type2   0
apple_type2   20
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried SUMIF()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column A is sorted, then you could also use `=IF(A1=A2,0,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B))` copied down:

[image]

This would be faster than using `COUNTIF` within the same formula, referring to Error 1004's answer (`COUNTIF` and `SUMIF` all need to 'look' at the range, so having two of these in the same formula will consume twice as much resources, but it has the advantage that it doesn't require column A to be sorted).

If you need to refresh the data a lot of times (new information got added for example), then I would advise sorting then using the formula I proposed.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. It is working faster. Thanks for your solution it's clever.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the formula and try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A3:$A$9,A2)>0,0,SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,A2,$B$2:$B$8))
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!